# How to set some String values in to an Alarm

Tags: android

I need to pass some values into `onReceive()` method in `BroadcastReceiver`. I'm implementing an Alarm and when alarm trigger out i need to show some text based on some of the text values i gained before? Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting `intent` in `public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent)`.
through intent you can get the value which you set.

This will put the value `intentObject.putExtra("key", "text");`

To get `intent.getExtras.getString("key");`